# <select> elements throwing off <div> alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand the basics of css applied to a test site that I'm working with.

Reducing the problem to it barest case I have three equal , two of which should contain  lists, the third of which does not.

The html is as follows:

```
<div id="Div1" class="Results">
   <select id="FirmList" size=10></select>   
</div>
<div id="Div2" class="Results">
</div>    
<div id="Div3" class="Results">
   <select id="PersonList" size =10></select> 
</div>
```

And the css as thus:

```
div {
  border: 1px dashed black;  
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 8px;
}

select {
  width: 290px;
}

.Results {
  border: 2px solid black;  
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If I comment out the  elements the three s align correctly.

Bringing in either  causes it's parent  to move down the page.  None of the other elements on the page (tables, headers and other divs) seem to affect the alignment in the same way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the `.Results` rule

```
.Results {
  border: 2px solid black;  
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/QBVz9/1/embedded/result/

---

It has nothing to do with the `select` elements. even if you put a single letter in the `.Results` elements it will cause the problem.

It has to do with the fact that you have turned the `div` elements to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: So why do the table / div elements not affect the positioning?

Comment: @Dan if you put a `div` inside with content it will cause the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/QBVz9/2/embedded/result/

Comment: @abhitalks floating comes with its own set of quirks you need to be aware of.

Comment: @Gaby - On my full example div 2 has 2 child divs, one containing a <table> and div 3 has a div containing a <table>.  It's only the <select> tags that are showing the misalignment. I'd have been less confused if the other elements had caused the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
.float-left {
float:left;
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KWg9x/)

A solution could be to add float on select element.